# Php extension zip, ZipArchive doesn't work with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, pecl, php-ziparchive

Sample code:

```
namespace myns;

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('/var/www/less/less_1.zip');

for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    echo $zip->getNameIndex($i);
}
```

When I try create namespace and use a ZipArchive I have an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myns\ZipArchive' not found 
in /var/www/less/test.php on line 4
```

Without namespace 'myns' it works fine.

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to access it using "global" namespace:

```
namespace myns;

$zip = new \ZipArchive;
```

See [namespaces documentation](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) for details

Answer (score 0):

If missing in system:

```
sudo apt install php-zip
```

From global space in php:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

From a namespace (no parenthesis):

```
namespace ZipSpace;
function zip(){
   $zip = new \ZipArchive;
   // ....
}
```

Use `\` everywhere in the name space to refer global.

To call:

```
\ZipSpace\zip()
```